# Can't create object from custom COM library

Tags: c#, dll, com, vb6, interop

I am currently working on a project that uses an old COM object written in C# (.Net 4) for web services communication.  It is used in a VB6 frontend.

The web services have changed, and I have updated the c# code and everything work as expected in unit test, but I can't instantiate the object from VB6.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017, so I would like to know if there is any known issues that could prevent building COM object.

I also tried to use it from PowerShell, and it doesn't work either.

On my project propoerties, "Register for COM Interop" and "Make assembly COM-Visible" are checked.

The interface is declared like this :

```
     [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch), Guid("7F77D9FF-9E12-4733-9C40-34B0EFB60CA0")]
public interface IRAMQClass
```

The class implementing it is declared like this :

```
    [Guid("743555BF-B670-4B90-9B76-650E807756CE")]
[ClassInterface(classInterfaceType:ClassInterfaceType.None)]    
[ProgId("wsRAMQ.RAMQClass")]
public class RAMQClass : IRAMQClass
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Thank you !

Comment: What happens when you try to reference/instantiate it?

Comment: From VB6, I can add the reference without any problem, I can see it in the object browser but when I instantiate it, I receive an automation error.

Comment: From PowerShell, I have this error when I try to create the object : + $object = New-Object -ComObject "wsRAMQ.RAMQClass"
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Object], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Have you registered the COM component.

Comment: From what I understand, Visual Studio does it automatically on rebuild when "Register for COM Interop" is checked, and from what I can see in then registrry, it seems to be !     I also tried with regasm /codebase /tlb and makes no diffrerence !

Comment: VB6 needs to be able to find your assembly, and any dependent assemblies.  The easiest way to do this is to include any required assemblies in the same directory as the VB6 executable.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but we finally decided to rewrite the VB6 code in C# and include it in a more modern application.  Your help has been appreciated !